# After restore, WhatsApp does't show photo anymore

Tags: whatsapp.app

After the restore from backup of my iPhone 4S I realised that photos in my Whatsapp chats are not present. Moreover, instead of each photos preview there are a question mark as in the photo reported here below:

[image]

I tried to solve the problem with:

- a reset of the phone;
- a battery pull;

But nothing change. 
Someone know how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with an iTunes restore.

In particular, using an older backup that was previous the one used having found this problem. In this manner, all the WhatsApp photo were present.